# FileResult not returning proper file type and file name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, epplus, fileresult

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with an ActionResult called `GenerateReport`.  I'm trying to return a byte array to save an Excel file.  Here are snippets:

```
var contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
var fileName = "Statistics.xlsx";
```

...

```
var fileBytes = package.GetAsByteArray();
return File(fileBytes, contentType, fileName);
```

When I'm prompted to save the file, it sometimes (but not always) asks what I want to do with "GenerateReport".  It's naming the file the same as the ActionResult and it's not giving it a file type.  I will request to save it and it will say that it failed to save.  I will select Retry and it will save fine. Then, if I rename it to an .xlsx, all of the data is there and correct.  I'm using IE9 and Chrome and I haven't noticed it happen in Chrome.  Unfortunately, it needs to work in IE9.

Does anyone know why it's not getting my content type and file name sometimes?

Comment: We serve hundred thousand files that way and never got anything like you report. Is it possible you set null filename sometimes?

Comment: Have you tried setting content-disposition like shown http://stackoverflow.com/a/16013045/372871 or like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3207274/372871?

Comment: @Wiktor - I've tried setting the filename right before I return the file.  The Response says that there is an attachment and the filename should be `Statistics.xlsx`.

Comment: @InSane - I've tried adding the following `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.xlsx");` and it does the same thing.

Comment: The correct MIME type for XLSX files is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla wouldn't you want to set the content disposition as an attachment, not inline? Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=..");

Comment: See if this helps, it is specific to EPPlus/Excel:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123352/set-download-location-with-epplus/31124809#31124809

Answer (score -1):

Check the response for Content-Encoding. It might be the same issue like here [PHP File Serving Script: Unreliable Downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617190/php-file-serving-script-unreliable-downloads)

Comment: What would be the ASP.NET equivalent of doing this?

Comment: First check if you have compression enabled with F12 tools in your browser under network tab by inspeting the http response. Then disable the compression as a test https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730629(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: No, I don't see anything in the Response about Content-Encoding.