# Download zip file in PHP not working

Tags: php, zip

Following is my code to download zip file using PHP.

```
function create_zip($files, $file_name, $overwrite = false) {

    foreach ($files as $imglink) {
        $img = file_get_contents($imglink);
        $destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'demoproject/downloads/' . time() . '.jpg';
        file_put_contents($destination_path, $img);
        $imgFiles[] = $destination_path;
    }

    if (file_exists($file_name) && !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }
    $valid_files = array();
    if (is_array($imgFiles)) {
        foreach ($imgFiles as $file) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    if (count($valid_files)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($file_name, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            echo "Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }
        foreach ($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
        }

        $count = $zip->numFiles;
        $resultArr = array();
        $resultArr['count'] = $count;
        $resultArr['destination'] = $file_name;

        $filename = $file_name;
        $filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'demoproject/';


        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath . $filename));
        ob_end_flush();
        @readfile($filepath . $filename);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here the `$filename` and `$filepath` containing the name and path of zip file respectively.

Ex:

`echo $filepath.$filename;`

```
Output : D:/wamp/www/demoproject/1357198557.zip
```

The issue is it displaying download window but showing the folder size `0 byte`. I am using windows7. See image below :

[image]

Comment: Please see that your folder have write permission so that file can be downloaded in it

Comment: Did you checked what file path is correct? Can the script fount it?

Comment: @AlexanderTaver: File path is correct

Comment: @YourCommonSense : what?? file path??

Comment: But your output shows c:/wamp/www/demo/1357197285.zip, without demoproject.

Comment: If filepath is correct And file shows for download aswell then check for the revelant code which "creates" the zip file. Because then zip file itself might be of 0 size. The code above doesnt do that

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : sorry that was a typo... I modified the path check now

Comment: @HankyPanky : No zip file containing the images and its size upto 168KB and more

Comment: You're on Windows. Do the slash type make any difference to filesize()? Windows native path will look like D:\wamp\www\demoproject\1357198557.zip

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : I tried that but problem is still persist

Comment: @Ultimate: try with my answer..

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : I have modified the code....plz check

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php points on two possible issues. 1. Function result is cached. You must run clearstatcache() to get real result. 2. You maybe on 32-bit system and file is larger than 2G.

Comment: @HankyPanky : I have modified the code....plz check

Comment: OK, I see you using timestamp as file name. Therefore, caching issue is irrelevant

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : My task is get album from facebook api, fetch all the photos behind scene from that album and zip them inside a folder on server. Then download the zip folder.

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : I have only issue with downloading the zip folder

Comment: Do file download correctly?

Comment: @AlexanderTaver : Whats wrong with file download code?

Comment: I have no idea. Looks OK. The only two things I found disturbing. 1. ob_end_flush() without ob_start() 2. @readfile . Do @ suppress only error messages or all the output? I don't remember exactly. But both can't explain zero result of filesize().

Comment: Does the zip file definitely have contents or is it in fact 0 bytes?

Comment: @popnoodles : No zip file containing images

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334471/content-length-header-always-zero

Comment: He's on WAMP, not ZendServer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this, Make sure you got proper `filesize`

```
$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
```