# Always send Content-Length in Apache?

Tags: apache, http-content-length

I'm loading a particularly large JSON string that is dynamically generated by PHP. To provide some feedback to the user, I want to show download progress.

I have the code figured out, and it works fine for static content such as images, JS files, etc. However, it doesn't seem to work for dynamic files.

This makes sense, since the dynamic files don't have predictable content length, but even if I add this in PHP:

```php
ob_start(function($c) {
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($c));
    return $c;
});
```

It still does not send the header (but if I add any other header it works fine).

Is there any way to force Apache to send the `Content-Length` header? Currently my only alternative is to save the output to a temporary file and redirect to it instead. This would work, but it's kind of messy so I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334471/content-length-header-always-zero

Comment: ... to be specific, the transfer encoding note in the Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It doesn't look like it's using chunked encoding (at least, `Transfer-Encoding` doesn't appear in the response headers) and I can't seem to get it to force HTTP/1.0...

Comment: Have you tried with a simple `ob_start(); /* output json */ $content = ob_get_clean(); header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content)); print($content);`? While it would be unexpected that your `ob_start` callback does not get executed, you can certainly expect anything unexpected from PHP.

Comment: What is the dynamic file extension?

Comment: The request is similar to `/ajax/getdata`, the file is `getdata.php`.

Comment: Is there some public URL where one could try this out? (The `ob_start`-with-callback one, that is?) That it would send any header but `Content-Length` is really strange.

Comment: so, maybe there is something in the Apache conf that overrides headers for php files?

Comment: Could you post the output of `curl -I <url>`?

Comment: Are you using error_reporting(-1)? Are you sure you can still send headers at that point? Did you try what lanzz said?

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem but in my case Content-Length header wasn't sent by Apache because the response was gzip compressed. When I disable compression the Content-Length was calculated and sent properly.

Below is htaccess setting to disable gzip compression for swf file only

```
<FilesMatch "\.swf$">
  SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have some changes in the `modules/http/http_filters` because Apache by default sends `Content-Length`.

Comment: Interestingly, I just wrote a quick PHP script to retrieve the file and the `Content-Length` header is there. But in the browser `xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` returns `null` and it doesn't show up in the console either.

Comment: @Kolink What headers do you have in Google Chrome in Network tab? (when you inspect that call). And be sure to look at response not request headers.

Comment: Sure enough the header is there. Okay, so why is IE10 not listing or acknowledging the `Content-Length` headers in some calls, but is in others???

Comment: @Kolink It looks like another problem right now. What are you using to handle XHR call, jQuery? BTW I think that IE is still really unpredictable browser (like everything from Microsoft), PHP is dangerous. And Apache, well... It was nice years ago, maybe it's time to try something faster like based on event-loop Nginx?

Comment: No jQuery, just plain XMLHttpRequest. It works fine for static files, which is the weird thing...

Comment: @Kolink IE is weird and you are brave using plain JS against IE :- ) Can you try the same thing using jQuery? (or any cross-browser library)

Comment: I adamantly refuse to use any library. They cause more unpredictable behaviour than they solve. See also [this image I made](http://adamhaskell.net/img/jquery.png).

Comment: @Kolink I disagree, but it's for long discussion. Can you please use jQuery and if it works then we can look how jQuery handles that issue and you can extract vanilla JavaScript code from it.

Comment: Not happening. Sorry. Even if it did work, how would it help?

Comment: @Kolink If jQuery works then we can have a look at its internals and see how it handles bug in IE. Just to make sure we are on the same page, CL in the headers is send but only IE has trouble to see it?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol needs a way to determine when a response has ended.  According to

[RFC2616 Section 4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html)

> 4.4 Message Length
>
> The transfer-length of a message is the length of the message-body as
>   it appears in the message; that is, after any transfer-codings have
>   been applied. When a message-body is included with a message, the
>   transfer-length of that body is determined by one of the following (in
>   order of precedence):
>
> 1.Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD request)
>   is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields,
>   regardless of the entity-header fields present in the message.
>
> 2.If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
>   defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6), unless
>   the message is terminated by closing the connection.
>
> 3.If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
>   transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent if
>   these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
>
> ```
>  header field is present). If a message is received with both a
>  Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>  the latter MUST be ignored.
> ```
>
> 4.If the message uses the media type "multipart/byteranges", and the transfer-length is not otherwise specified, then this self- delimiting
>   media type defines the transfer-length. This media type MUST NOT be
>   used unless the sender knows that the recipient can parse it; the
>   presence in a request of a Range header with multiple byte- range
>   specifiers from a 1.1 client implies that the client can parse
>   multipart/byteranges responses.
>
> ```
>    A range header might be forwarded by a 1.0 proxy that does not
>    understand multipart/byteranges; in this case the server MUST
>    delimit the message using methods defined in items 1,3 or 5 of
>    this section.
> ```
>
> 5.By the server closing the connection. (Closing the connection cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since that would leave
>   no possibility for the server to send back a response.)
>
> For compatibility with HTTP/1.0 applications, HTTP/1.1 requests
>   containing a message-body MUST include a valid Content-Length header
>   field unless the server is known to be HTTP/1.1 compliant. If a
>   request contains a message-body and a Content-Length is not given, the
>   server SHOULD respond with 400 (bad request) if it cannot determine
>   the length of the message, or with 411 (length required) if it wishes
>   to insist on receiving a valid Content-Length.
>
> All HTTP/1.1 applications that receive entities MUST accept the
>   "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6), thus allowing this mechanism
>   to be used for messages when the message length cannot be determined
>   in advance.
>
> Messages MUST NOT include both a Content-Length header field and a
>   non-identity transfer-coding. If the message does include a non-
>   identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored.
>
> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is
>   allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in
>   the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an
>   invalid length is received and detected.

You can't just randomly add headers and expect them to be obeyed (other headers can override). You need to control all possibly overriding headers generated in the first place.

According to this question ([How to make PHP generate Chunked response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481858/how-to-make-php-generate-chunked-response))  a good way to force "Chunked" is to set Transfer-Encoding and to `flush`.  Maybe those two aren't strictly needed. Would there be any extraneous flushes anywhere before you start buffering?

Answer (score 0):

From the `ob_start` documentation:

> ```
> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no 
> output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored 
> in an internal buffer.
> ```

Note the "*other than headers*" bit -- the `ob_start()` callback is not called until the buffer is being flushed (or thrown away), at this point it's too late to use `header()`. I'm guessing you don't have error logging turned on, I see this in my error log:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent 
  in /usr/local/apache2/apps/testing/test2.php on line 6
```

The callback lets you modify the buffer before sending, but as this contains only body data, you also cannot prepend a new header (it will appear in the content if you try, once for each chunk for chunked transfers).

Your code should call instead `header("Content-Length: ...")` once you know the size, *before any other output*. When a `Content-Length:` header is found, chunked transfer will not take place.

If you *really* need to force HTTP/1.0 (you don't), you can do it in `httpd.conf` with the special variables:

```
SetEnv downgrade-1.0 1
SetEnv force-response-1.0 1
```

You can put those in `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` for example, or use `mod_rewrite`'s "`env`" flag for more control.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few JS files that were around 1MB that didn't get Content-Length header (unlike other, smaller JS files). The fact that Content-Length header is not mandatory with HTTP/2 and having a somewhat flaky Internet connection resulted in a very hard to debug error where the files were sometimes delivered only partially. The solution was to increase DeflateBufferSize https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#DeflateBufferSize