# XMLHttpRequest returns null on Apache server but not lo

Tags: javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest

The following snippet of code computes the size of files located at `url`  on my local system using Javascript

```
//returns file size given a URL
function getFileSize(url, key)
{
    var fileSize = '';
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                fileSize = this.getResponseHeader('content-length');

                //saves size in dictionary sizes
                sizes[key] = fileSize;
             }
        }
  };
  http.send();
}
```

When I deploy the code to my Apache server, however, `this.getResponseHeader` returns null, although the provided url correctly points to a file. I am considering different options for why this is the case (e.g., incorrect file permissions) but haven't found a solution yet. I also followed [this link](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/set-access-control-allow-origin-cors-headers-apache/) to change my server configuration to allow CORS but that didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the network tab, whats the status code of the request?

Comment: @Khalil - at a guess, 200 ... since it has to be 200 for `this.getResponseHeader('content-length')` to even execute, let alone return "null"

Comment: You don't need to guess, the network tab in the dev tools will show you the status of the request.

Comment: Yes, the status of the request is 200 both locally and on the server

Comment: While you are looking at the network tab, is the Apache server including the **optional** `content-length` header in the response?

Comment: It was not included and I couldn't figure out why. I finally found out that some settings in my .htaccess were preventing the server to send content-length (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. In my `.htaccess`, I had added some filters to allow for HTML compression as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDK2c7rokOw). However, this made my Apache server not include `content-length` in the html response (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464516/always-send-content-length-in-apache) for more details). By getting rid of HTML compression in `.htaccess`, `content-length` is now included by the server.